# MS SQL Select/Where Function Only Matching on First Digit of Value

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-functions

I have the following tables in my MS SQL database -

**Downtime**

```
Row | Time | Running | FaultID | Fault
----|------|---------|---------|-------
 1  |00:00 |    1    |   110   |   -
 2  |00:10 |    0    |   110   |   A
 3  |02:00 |    1    |   320   |   -
 4  |02:15 |    0    |   1     |   A
 5  |02:40 |    1    |   350   |   -
 6  |04:00 |    0    |   158   |   A
 7  |04:10 |    1    |   110   |   -
 8  |04:20 |    0    |   210   |   C
 7  |04:30 |    1    |   110   |   -
 9  |06:10 |    0    |   28    |   C
 10 |06:40 |    1    |   110   |   -
```

**Fault Codes**

```
FaultCode | Fault
----------|-------
 1        |A
 28       |C
 110      |D
 158      |E
 210      |F
 320      |G
 350      |H
```

So the 'Fault Codes' table is a list of all the code definitions and 'Downtime' is the actual live data.  The Fault column in the 'Downtime' table is a computed column with this SQL -

```
(case when [Running]=(1) then NULL else [dbo].[UDF_KG78Faults]([FaultID]) end)
```

And the UDF that this is linked to has this code -

```
FUNCTION [dbo].[UDF_KG78Faults] (@FaultID VarChar)
    RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
    AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @FaultDesc VARCHAR(100)
            SELECT @FaultDesc = Fault
            From KG78FaultCodes
            WHERE FaultCode = @FaultID
        RETURN @FaultDesc
```

Now here's my problem -

Fault ID should be returning a different fault description for each unique number.  What is actually happening is that when the value is something like 1, 15, 110, 150, etc.; it only matches using the first digit rather than the whole entry.

The FaultID column was initially formatted as an integer, but I was getting int conversion errors due to the data being pulled in.  Changing it to Varchar fixed one problem but created this new one.

Is it possible to edit my UDF to match on the entire entry rather than just the first digit?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring `varchar` without (length) - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should always provide a length for all `varchar` or `nvarchar` variables/parameters.

Comment: Thank you @SqlZim.  Nice link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a length to @FaultID in your function definition (make it VARCHAR(3) or something like that).  If you don't specify a VARCHAR length it will default to 1 so the FaultID you're passing into the UDF is getting truncated to 1 character.